# One step delay while using ShouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: reactjs

In my ReactJS project i have a `Table` and filters for it. I got `JSON` file using `axious` from `Django REST` host. So i have a class for my main `Table`:

```
class MainTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      count: 0
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props.link + " : " + nextProps.link);
    return JSON.stringify(this.props.link) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.link);
  }

  render() {
    axios.get(this.props.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results});
        this.setState({count: res.data.count});
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Label> We got {this.state.count} elements in our database. </Label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Table hover striped bordered responsive size="sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.results.map(result =>
                <tr key={result.fileId}>
                  <td>{result.name}</td>
                  <td>{result.name}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But when i run my app, i got one step delay in it, here is log :

```
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&" bundle.js:53418:7
./src/App.js
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&" bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall&" bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcrsutc&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcrsutc& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcrsutc&" bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcrsutc& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&" bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall&" bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltcall& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&"  bundle.js:53418:7
"http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3& : http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=10&ORIGIN=dcseltc3&"
```

It makes data check twice and rerun my render only after next checking. Maybe i did something wrong. I'm new with `ReactJS` and I think it should be easy answer for it.

Comment: You shouldnt be setting state in the middle of a render.
The axios request should be in an action and the data should be populated via Redux/mobx/flux or which state manager you choose.
If you do not want to do it, You can fetch your data in componentWillMount/componentDidMount and then set the state there.

Comment: Even without state manager, api call and new setState should be made in componentDidMount step. It is considered bad practice in componentWillMount : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: If i will put my `axios` in `render()` without `shouldComponentUpdate`  it will hit my host a few times per second, so I wanted to change it. If i use `componentDidMount()`, my `MainTable` doesn't refresh with new data after I sent new props to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render is always called after a new state instance is set, so it should refresh with the new data if you put your setState in the componentDidMount(). And setState only once.

```
class MainTable extends React.Component {
...
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.props.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results, count: res.data.count});
    });
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    axios.get(nextProps.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results, count: res.data.count});
    });
}
...
render() {
 return ...
}
```

Comment: But it still load my Table only once. When i change my link with filters, my `Table` is load with the same start data. In my Main i use just `<MainTable link={link} />` and link is an object i change with my filters to make request for `REST` data.

Comment: Well you didn't really mention it in your post, have a look at componentWillReceiveProps, it is called every time a new props is pass to the component, i'll edit my post : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Sorry, will be more precise in the future posts. Ty for answer.

Comment: No problem, have a deep look at this page : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html  It handle most problem you may face using react